# How to detect if I'm connected on the console

Tags: linux, tty, console

I would like to find a reliable way to detect if I'm connected on the console before doing network maintenance.

So far I found this :

```bash
$ tty | grep /dev/tty
/dev/tty2 # Connected on the console
$ ssh localhost tty | grep /dev/tty
$ # Remotely connected
```

Is this a reliable way to do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just running `tty` by itself will tell you whether or not you're connected to *a* console -- which could be a local virtual console, but it could also be a pseudo-terminal. For example:

```
ssh -t localhost tty
/dev/pts/9
```

That `-t` flag means "allocate a tty", and that is the **default** behavior for an interactive ssh session.

So you can't just ask "am I connected to a tty or not?", but you **can** make decision based on the device return by the `tty` command. Something like:

```
case "$(tty)" in
  /dev/tty[0-9])
    echo "I am on a local console."
    ;;

  /dev/ttyS[0-9]|/dev/ttyACM[0-9]|/dev/ttyUSB[0-9])
    echo "I am on a serial console."
    ;;

  *)
    echo "I am not on a local console"
esac
```